# Change the app name of a new google calendar app from "quickstart"

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console

My NodeJS Google Calendar App's google permission page titles my app as "quickstart" , how do I change this version. I am new to stack overflow so please excuse if I didn't get the format of asking a question right.

I have already tried changing the name of the app in the credentials.json file.

I was hoping there would be a way to change the app name in google's permissions page as "quickstart" does not look very professional.

Comment: Welcome to stack, if your looking for formatting tips.  Maybe next time pop in a picture. All i did was add a few tags to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the flags. I will defiantly do that the next time around. (Probably not very far away as this project is a lot of work :D)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name that pops up on the consent screen is configured in Google developer console

[image]

You can control everything though this page.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked plus now i have cool auth photo as well.

Comment: You will never beet my auth photo 

Comment: Quick link if anyone wants to skip Google Search: https://console.developers.google.com/